# Changing phone region

Tags: 8.1

Will I be able to change phone region and then swap it back again? Currently I've set to united states to have access to Cortana. I want to change region, download few apps that are available in my country and change it back to united states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you should be able to change your phone region without restrictions. I've switched mine multiple times to enable certain features (like Cortana) or install certain apps, and have never run into problems with switching it back afterwards.

Comment: Great, I just wanted to be sure because I don't want to loose Cortana :P

Comment: Don't worry, she's very loyal ;)